# Ignore specific character: -

Tags: php, replace, character

I want to ignore a specific character using php. So when a user adds this character in the textbox. the php scripts filters it out first. I tried something and came up with this:

```
<?php
    $datetogoto = $_GET['datetogoto'];
    $pattern = '-';
    $replace = '';
    preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $datetogoto);
    header('Location: ../index.php?newsdate='.$datetogoto);
?>
```

So what it wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try using `str_replace`

```
$datetogoto = $_GET['datetogoto'];

$datetogoto = str_replace("-","", $datetogoto);
```

Ref: https://www.php.net/str_replace

Or , if you want get date format whatever you sent in query string, then use `urlencode()`

```
header('Location: ../index.php?newsdate='.urlencode($datetogoto));
```

Answer (score 0):

[**PHP regex needs delimiters**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php), so use it like this:

```
$pattern = '/-/';
```

OR else use `str_replace`:

```
str_replace('-', $replace, $datetogoto);
```